# JavaFX Linechart ClassCastException Integer to String

Tags: java, javafx, classcastexception

For a personal project I created a program which fetches stock data from markitondemand.com without any problem. In an object I store some values in a values field that is a HashMap.

Now I want to display the values of that object in a line chart in JavaFX. Currently I have the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.calculateRequiredSize(CategoryAxis.java:378)
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.autoRange(CategoryAxis.java:363)
at javafx.scene.chart.Axis.computePrefHeight(Axis.java:577)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:927)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1435)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.layoutChartChildren(XYChart.java:687)
at javafx.scene.chart.Chart$1.layoutChildren(Chart.java:94)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1079)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1085)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$31(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$405(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

In the stacktrace is no link to my own code, so I don't know how to solve this issue.

This is a print screen of the values that are fetched for Apple:
[image: Values for object from Apple's stock]

I loop over these values so I can add them to the series that is used as data for the line chart.
Code example:
(stockToDraw.getValues() returns the values displayed in the screenshot)

```
int i = 1;
    for(String key : stockToDraw.getValues().keySet()) {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(i, stockToDraw.getValues().get(key)));
        i++;
    }
```

My linechart is declared as follows:

```
final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

@FXML
LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
```

With the code samples above, I get an ClassCastException that an Integer can't be casted to a String, but I don't know how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

As being mentioned in the comments, the stacktrace referred to an CategoryAxis. This axis is includes in the FXML code as follow:

```
<LineChart fx:id="lineChart" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="120.0" prefHeight="470.0" prefWidth="581.0">
    <xAxis>
      <CategoryAxis label="Days" side="BOTTOM" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
      <NumberAxis label="Value" side="LEFT" />
    </yAxis>
  </LineChart>
```

Comment: It looks like `stockToDraw.getValues().get(key)` returns a String and you are trying to use it as a Number.

Comment: stockToDraw is a HashMap of <String, Integer> ?

Comment: @Steven Nope, HashMap<String, Double>

Comment: @markbernard I tried to change it to ```(Number) Double.valueOf(stockToDraw.getValues().get(key))``` and ``` Double.valueOf(stockToDraw.getValues().get(key))``` but with no success

Comment: The stack trace is referring to a `CategoryAxis`: none of the code snippets you have posted include a `CategoryAxis` at all. So the code you posted is not related to the error. Create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: @James_D Updated my answer with the FXML code that has a CategoryAxis

Comment: So there are quite a few things wrong here. First, it is *always* a mistake to initialize variables that are annotated `@FXML`. You initialize `lineChart` to a `new LineChart<Number, Number>`, but when you load the FXML file, the `FXMLLoader` will then assign `lineChart` the element that was defined in the FXML file - i.e. a `LineChart` with a `CategoryAxis` and a `NumberAxis`.  Since `CategoryAxis` extends `Axis<String>`, the line chart is now expecting `x`-values to be `String`s. You are passing in `Number`s for both coordinates: hence the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: So it's not at all clear what you actually intend to do. Why are you setting a `CategoryAxis` in the FXML file if you are wanting both axes to be numeric?

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your comment. I solved my problem. I answered my own question but I can accept your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @James_D pointed out in the comments, I was initializing the linechart multiple times.

I removed the initializer and changed it to

```
@FXML
LineChart<String, Double> lineChart;
```

After that I changed `XYChart.Series<Number, Number>` to `XYChart.Series<String, Double>` in all the required places.

After this I tested in an it has the following result:
[image: Result of working linechart]